# How to prevent IndexError of pandas series in a nested loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas, index-error

I have a nested loop. In the outer loop, I iterate through MORE keys than the dataframe[key]s in the inner loop. That causes an IndexError (key cannot be found in dataframe[key].
I need a way to check if the keys match.

f.e. just the key columns:

```
dfKeys                    dataframe
-------                   --------
 key                         key
  1                           1
  1                           3
  3                           5
  3                           9
  3
  4
  4
  5
  5
  5
  5
  8
  8
  9
  9
  9 

grouped=dfKeys.groupby('key')
for key, group in grouped:
    if ((group.someCol=='someVal').any() or ~(group.someCol.isin(someArray).any())):
        if(key in dataframe['key']): #######this did not solve it, always false (but there have to be some matches) 
            foundIndex=dataframe[dataframe['key']==key].index.values.astype(int)[0] #INDEXERROR after some loops if there is no 'if' above
            dataframe.loc[foundIndex,'myCol']='myVal'
```

Type of `dataframe['key']` is  pandas series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but I can use try-except

```
grouped=dfKeys.groupby('key')
for key, group in grouped:
    if ((group.someCol=='someVal').any() or ~(group.someCol.isin(someArray).any())):
        try: 
            foundIndex=dataframe[dataframe['key']==key].index.values.astype(int)[0] 
            dataframe.loc[foundIndex,'myCol']='myVal'
        except IndexError: print('key not found, continue')
```

Comment: Did you try using the `.get()` method on the `pandas.Series` object to check for a value, as I added in my answer? It would be much cleaner than adding a try/except block.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a list your looping through, then you can check if the index is within the length of the list:

```py
if key < len(list):
```

If it's a dictionary you can check if the key exists:

```py
if key in dict:
```

If you want to get a key from a dict if it exists, and return a default value if it doesn't, then you can use `dict.get()`:

```py
value = dict.get(key, default)
```

**EDIT:**

According to the documentation for pandas.Series, you can use the `Series.get()` method to get an item for a given key. Just as with `dict.get()` you can specify a default value to return if the key wasn't found:

```py
if mySeries.get(myKey, 'default') != 'default':
    #This code will only run if it found `myKey` in `mySeries`
```

The pandas.Series documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html#pandas.Series.get

Comment: What datatype is `dataframe['key']`?

Comment: it's pandas series

Comment: I edited my answer to include how to check for keys in a panda.Series object.

Comment: @Sel Then you are checking for keys that does not exist. Make sure you are using the correct value in the `get()` call. Print out the values that you are comparing, it will likely help you find the issue very quickly.

Comment: I am sure that there is the same key because I printed the condition you recommended in my try-block. Since my try block runs, it finds the same key. But printing your condition, it always outputs 'default'

Comment: @Sel Then it seems you have discovered a bug in pandas. You should report the issue to the pandas developers and let them know that `pandas.Series.get()` is not working as intended. It will help them find and fix the bug.